# How to test object returned by method?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, standards

I have started practicing TDD approach. I am pretty much new to unit testing.

I would like to know how to test some object returned by an method?

for example if I have following classes (please forgive me for public variables)

```
 class Person {
     public String firstName;
     public String lastName;
     public int age;

     private void getFirstAndLastName(fullName) {
         // some logic to split name into first name and last name
         // and then assign first name and last name to data members
     }

     public Person(String fullName) {
         getFirstAndLastName(fullName);
     }
 }
```

and person creator class

```
public class PersonBuilder {
    public static Person buildPerson(String fullName) {
        return new Person("Sachin Tendulkar");
    }

}
```

I want to test the output of `buildPerson()` method of `PersonBuilder` class.
If I want to make sure that the firsName of object returned by `buildPerson()` method is 'Sachin' and lastName is 'Tendulkar' then how should I write test code for this?

Should I check member variables of Person class manually like `object.FirstName.equals("Sachin")` or is there any other better way to test in this kind of situation? What

is the standard way to test it?

and by the way, I am using Java and JUnit.

Please enlighten !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in your case you would check the member variables.

But you really should use properties instead of public variables. You would check the properties then.

Comment: thanks a lot. I used public variables just to make my example smaller. In my actual project, I do follow coding standards and use getters and setters.